# Dependecy injection for HttpConfiguration in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector, httpconfiguration

I am getting an error in my `HelpController`:

> The constructor of type HelpController contains the parameter with
>   name 'config' and type HttpConfiguration that is not registered.
>   Please ensure HttpConfiguration is registered, or change the
>   constructor of HelpController.

Is there any alternative to resolve this issue because I use `Configuration` to get `Configuration.GetModelDescriptionGenerator();`

```cs
public class HelpController : Controller
{
    private const string ErrorViewName = "Error";

    public HelpController(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        Configuration = config;
    }

    public HttpConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    ...

    public ActionResult ResourceModel(string modelName)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(modelName))
        {
            ModelDescriptionGenerator modelDescriptionGenerator = Configuration.GetModelDescriptionGenerator();
            ModelDescription modelDescription;
            if (modelDescriptionGenerator.GeneratedModels.TryGetValue(modelName, out modelDescription))
            {
                return View(modelDescription);
            }
        }

        return View(ErrorViewName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried registering the `HttpConfiguration`?

Comment: @Steven how can i register it with-out interface?

Comment: I think I don't really understand your question. You just register it. Try `container.RegisterSingleton<HttpConfiguration>(config);`.

Comment: than @Steven it worked

Comment: Did you get this suggestion from @Steven working? I don't have `config` defined in my Global.asax and if I try just `container.RegisterSingleton<HttpConfiguration>()` I get `For the container to be able to create HttpConfiguration it should have only one public constructor: it has 2`

Comment: Interestingly I have just found that if I remove / comment out the line `container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` in my Global.asax but keep `container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);` my (MVC) Controllers still get their dependencies injected but the HelpController still works as before. I've had to use a Hybrid LifeStyle though otherwise you get lifestyle errors at runtime presumably due to a mismatch between WebAPI and MVC.

Comment: @Caltor: If you're mixing Web API and MVC in the same project (which means you always run it inside IIS), you should typically only use `WebRequestLifestyle` as scoped lifestyle. There should be no need for a hybrid lifestyle.

Comment: @Caltor: You should _not_ remove the call to `RegisterMvcControllers`, because that would blind Simple Injector's verification and diagnostics system.

Comment: @Steven OK I've put the `RegisterMvcControllers` back in. I was able to resolve this problem by changing the constructor above to private (thanks to a suggestion from a colleague). The OP original code seems to omit the parameterless constructor that I have in my VS generated code which makes this work. I'll post the fixed code as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change your constructor to `private` and put back in the parameterless constructor as generated by VS. Your `HelpController` should look like this.

```
public class HelpController : Controller
{
    private const string ErrorViewName = "Error";

    public HelpController()
        : this(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
    {
    }

    private HelpController(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        Configuration = config;
    }


    public HttpConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
}
```